# Quick Algebra question regarding time it takes to get something done?

Tags: linear-algebra

Al and Bob can do a job together in $t$ days. If Al worked alone $2.5$ days longer than $t$, and Bob worked alone $1.5$ days less than $t$, then each would complete $1/2$ of the job. How many days does it take Al, working alone, to do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let Al take $a$ days to complete the work.

Let the work to be done denotwd by W.

So work done by Al in one day $= \frac Wa$

Similarly Let Bob take $b$ days to complete the work.

So work done by Bob in one day $= \frac Wb$

Given :

$$ \left (\frac 1a + \frac 1b \right )t=W \tag 1$$

$$ \left (\frac 1a \right )(t + 2.5)= \frac W2 \tag2     $$

$$ \left(\frac 1b \right)(t - 1.5)= \frac W2 \tag 3$$

$(2) + (3) - (1):$

$$ \frac 5a= \frac3b$$

Putting into equation $ (1)$

$$ \frac {8t}{3a}=W$$

$$ \frac {8t/3}{a}=W$$

So, it takes $ \dfrac {8t}{3}$ days for Al to complete hs work.